# Is the size of a vector simply the size of the sum of its parts?

Tags: c++, vector, size

For example, a float is 4 bytes. Does this mean that a vector containing 10 floats is exactly 40 bytes?

Comment: Now are you asking about `vector_name.size()` or `sizeof(vector_name)`?

Comment: @NathanOliver ummm...what exactly is the difference?

Comment: The first one is useful, the second, not so much

Comment: To answer this simply: no, in no case the size of vector will be `size() * <size_of_element>`, also it may occupy different parts of memory (the `vector` instance itself may elsewhere, than the continuous memory buffer holding the values). And it is implementation dependent, the standard does not define how `vector` should be implemented, so different platforms/compilers may need different amount of additional memory.  If you have large amount of elements in the vector, then you can roughly calculate memory consumption as `capacity() * <size_of_element>`, as the `vector` instance is constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One may interpret the "size" of a vector in different ways:

1. `vector::size()` gives the *number* of elements currently stored in
   the vector, regardless of the memory they allocate. So
   `myVector.size()` in your case would be `10`
2. `vector:capacity()` gives you the number of the elements for which the vector has allocated memory so far. Note that a vector, when continuously appending elements, allocates memory in "chunks", i.e. it might reserve space for 50 new elements at once in order to avoid repeated memory allocs. So `capacity() >= size()` is always true.
3. `sizeof(myVector)` would give you the size of the data structure `vector` necessary for managing a dynamically increasing series of elements. It typically contains dynamically allocated memory, which is not reflected by `sizeof`, such that `sizeof` is of less use in most cases.

See the following code:

```
int main() {

    vector<float> fv;
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        fv.push_back(1.0);
    }
    cout << "size(): " << fv.size() << endl;
    cout << "capacity(): " << fv.capacity() << endl;
    cout << "sizeof(fv): " << sizeof(fv) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
size(): 10
capacity(): 16
sizeof(fv): 24
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

A `std::vector` has 3 different sizes.  There is the size of the vector object itself and you get that with `size(std::vector<some_type>)`.  This size isn't really useful for anything though.  Typically this will be the size of three pointers as that is how vector is typically implemented.

The second size is what is returned from the `size()` member function.  The value returned from this is the number of elements in the vector.  This is the "size" most people use when talking about the size of the vector.

The last size a vector has is the total number of elements it has allocated currently.  That is obtained from using the `capacity` member function.

So a vector holding 10 floats needs to use at least 10 floats worth of memory but it could be using more as the `capacity()` is allowed to be grater then its `size()`.  But size of the vector object itself (`sizeof(name_of_vector)`) will be some value and that value will never change no matter how many elements you add into the vector.